# How to store filename from a parsed array?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I have a parsed array named $result and I want to store all filenames from $result to a variable or to another array? Or even using $result to call only filename. I want the filenames, because I want to download all csv files from today's date from ftp server. 
Here's the output of $result when I dump it:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> array(10) {
        ["isdir"]=> bool(false)
        ["perms"]=> string(14) "////-rw-r--r--"
        ["number"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["owner"]=> string(7) "4664210"
        ["group"]=> string(5) "15000"
        ["size"]=> string(5) "79360"
        ["month"]=> string(3) "Nov"
        ["day"]=> string(2) "20"
        ["time/year"]=> string(5) "03:55"
        ["name"]=> string(10) "order3.csv"
    }
    [1]=> array(10) {
        ["isdir"]=> bool(false)
        ["perms"]=> string(14) "////-rw-r--r--"
        ["number"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["owner"]=> string(7) "4664210"
        ["group"]=> string(5) "15000"
        ["size"]=> string(5) "79360"
        ["month"]=> string(3) "Nov"
        ["day"]=> string(2) "20"
        ["time/year"]=> string(5) "04:34"
        ["name"]=> string(10) "order4.csv" }
    }
```

I get this output from this code:

```
$result = parse_ftp_rawlist($files, false); // Function to parse array
var_dump ($result);
```

Comment: `I want to store all filenames from $result to a variable or to another array?` Do you asking us what do you want to do? Anyway, why do you want to create another array, why do not use this `$result` directly?

Answer (score 0):

there was a function in the documentation written by someone as an example. You can re-use it with some tweaks.

```
function listDetailed($resource, $directory = '.')
{
    if (is_array($children = @ftp_rawlist($resource, $directory)))
    {
        $result = array();
        $items = array();

        foreach ($children as $child)
        {
            $chunks = preg_split("/\s+/", $child);
            list($item['rights'], $item['number'], $item['user'], $item['group'], $item['size'], $item['month'], $item['day'], $item['time'],$item['name']) = $chunks;
            $item['type'] = $chunks[0]{0} === 'd' ? 'directory' : 'file';
            if($item['type'] == 'file')
            {
                $result['files'][] = $item['name'];
            }

        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```